# Nagios 4.0.x - Mail notification only sending to the first contact of contactgroup

Tags: linux, nagios

I have a working Nagios solution since about 4 years. I noticed some time after updating Nagios 3.5.x to a 4.0.8 version, one person havn't received any error notifications.

Nothing changed on our mail configuration on this server or our exchange server we use in our company. No changes to our Nagios config files also.

The concerned file must be the `contacts.cfg`
I have a contactgroup configured like this :

```
define contactgroup{
contactgroup_name       admins
alias                   Nagios Administrators
members                 Admin1,Admin2
 }
```

The strange thing is that the "Admin2" don't get any mail notification, if I inverse the order of my users  like this :

```
define contactgroup{
contactgroup_name       admins
alias                   Nagios Administrators
members                 Admin2,Admin1
 }
```

It's Admin1 who doesn't have any notification.

Nothing was made between Nagios 3.5 and 4.0 according officials changelog.
Is there any way I can let Nagios notify all the users in a contactgroups ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the exact version you're using, but your problem might be resolved with an upgrade to the latest (4.0.8 currently).

For example, you might want to see the [Nagios 4 changelog](https://www.nagios.org/projects/nagioscore/history/nagios-4-version-history), specifically the bullet points under 4.0.5, including:

> Fixed bug #594: Nagios 4 fix contactgroups parsing (Alexey Dvoryanchikov, Eric Stanley)

It's possible you're already running a newer version, since 4.0.5 came out April 2014.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the exact version. I'm already running the current 4.0.8 version.

Comment: Seems like you should open a new bug, then ;-)